# Ember - How to order a ArrayController with new models

Tags: ember.js

I have an ArrayController (categories) that contains many ObjectController (category). Each category have an attribute called "category_order_nm". I have set my

```
App.CategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'category',
    sortAscending: true,
    sortProperties: ['category_order_nm']
});
```

So far so good! My store fetch all my categories from my API, and they are ordered they way they should. Now when my user click on "Add" that's where it becomes Edgy. I can add as much Category as I want, they will order, but only within the new categories, like if they were a whole different Array. Let me show you an exemple to clarify. I have these initials categories :

Category1 category_order_nm : 10
Category2 category_order_nm : 11
Category3 category_order_nm : 12

And I add these categories

Category4 category_order_nm : 3
Category5 category_order_nm : 2
Category6 category_order_nm : 1

They will show in the following order:

Category1 category_order_nm : 10
Category2 category_order_nm : 11
Category3 category_order_nm : 12
Category6 category_order_nm : 1
Category5 category_order_nm : 2
Category4 category_order_nm : 3

Last information that could be useful. When a user click on my route CategoriesAddRoute. This happen:

```
App.CategoriesAddRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.newRecord();
    },
)};

App.CategoriesAddController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({   
    needs: ['categories'],
    newRecord: function() {
        record = this.store.createRecord( 'category', 
                                          {
                                              id: 4,
                                              category_active_bo: true,
                                              category_name_fr_sh: 'Nouvelle categorie',
                                              category_order_nm: 0,
                                          }
                                        );
        alert(this.get('controllers.categories').get('length')) // Given our previous example: 6
        this.get('controllers.categories').pushObject(record);
        alert(this.get('controllers.categories').get('length')) // Given our previous example: 7
        this.set('content', record);
    },
 )};
```

EDIT: This is my template :

```
<script data-template-name="categories-template" type="text/x-handlebars">
        <li class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" {{bindAttr data-target="category_collapse"}}>
            {{ category_name_fr_sh }}
            <button type="button" {{action destroyRecord this}}  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right">Effacer</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right">Modifier</button>
        </li>  
    {{#if category_children_ids}}     
        <div {{bindAttr id="category_collapse_target"}} class="collapse">
            {{#each category_children_ids}}
                {{render "categories-template" this}}
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    {{/if}} 
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="categories">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {{#link-to 'categories.add' tagName="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"}}Ajouter{{/link-to}}
        <ul class="list-group">                          
            {{#each category in controller}}
                {{{render "categories-template" this}}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="content">
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the template where you list the records with {{#each ...}}?

Comment: Sure give me a minute updating the post

Comment: Done, I guess this is where my mistake is since I have nothing that tells them to order?

Comment: I have reupdated my question I have two template that you might want to take a look at.

Comment: Can you put your relevant code in that jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/sqWgn/. Already have all dependencies emberjs, data etc.

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior Here http://jsfiddle.net/H5xEK/1/ You will notice two bugs I have, first the one I explain in the questoin, the second is that my "recursive template" doesn't work really well because it duplicates childs. Anyway take a look and thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Your problem is that you are recursivelly showing all children, but just the first level of elements is sorted. Give a look in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/jFCkF/3/. The column space between the elements represent the object graph. I can see that you just want to create and edit the categories right? I think going recursivelly isn't needed, since that all categories will be present in the first level. What do you think?

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior Sorry, I was out of town during the weekend. Actually, I don't want to show all children in the first level. This is another bug I have to fix. I'd like to show only the "root" categories. The children would only appear on a click (using bootstrap:collapse).

Comment: No problem. I updated your sample, now just the first level is displayed but is possible to expand to the children clicking in the parent. Please give a look http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/jFCkF/5/. For example clicking in Computed will expand to Dell, clicking in Dell will expand to Motherboard.

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior thanks, the last thing in my initial question is, how can I make them order properly. When I add a category, if you change the default value to any number it will go at the end. If you add a second category it will do the same. Add a couple of categories you will understand what I mean. Thanks again for helping me. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayController extend the Sortable mixin, you can simply do something like this:

songsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: songs,
  sortProperties: ['trackNumber'],
  sortAscending: true
});

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html

Comment: Unfortunately I've read that part of the doc at least 10 times but it really doesn't help me.